# How to get rid of the external white background of RoundedCornerShape

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I'm trying to make a little indicator light- text in a rounded rectangle where the background of the rounded rectangle changes depending on indicator state and the rest of the background is either black or transparent. I'm finding that the external corners of the shape are filled in with what seems to be a default white colour and not the colour of the containing object's background.

In this example, by my understanding, every background should be either green, blue or red. The white bits in the image shouldn't be there. Does anyone know what's wrong? I'm running Android Studio 2020.3.1 patch 3

. [image]

```
fun IndicatorLight() {
 
    Surface(modifier = Modifier.padding(4.dp)
        .background(Color.Green)) {
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .clip(RoundedCornerShape(20.dp))
                .background(Color.Red)
                .padding(3.dp)
        ) {
            Box(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .padding(4.dp)
                    .background(Color.Blue)
            ) {
                Text(
                    text = text,
                    style = TextStyle(
                        color = foreground,
                        fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
                        fontSize = 24.sp
                    )
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The surface has already a property named `color` to change the background color.

So change your code like this

```
Surface(
    color = Color.Green
) {}
```

Remove that padding from the surface and give it into the box if you want that Box to get 4.dp padding from the surface. And yeah modifier order is important so be careful about that. I have given padding before and after the background so that you can test by removing or reducing those padding how it's working.

You can change your full code like the one below

```
Surface(
    color = Color.Green
) {
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .padding(5.dp)
            .clip(RoundedCornerShape(20.dp))
            .background(Color.Red)
            .padding(5.dp)
    ) {
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(5.dp)
                .background(Color.Blue)
                .padding(5.dp)
        ) {
            Text(
                text = "Text",
                style = TextStyle(
                    color = Color.White,
                    fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
                    fontSize = 24.sp
                )
            )
        }
    }
}
```

You will get this.

[image: result]

Comment: Thanks for answering. It's a useful alternative but I've accepted Marsk's answer because it explains specifically why my attempt didn't work rather than just doing it a different way,

Comment: Second thoughts, this is one that works as expected and it's clear that it does because of the screenshot!

Comment: You have also changed the order of Modifiers. At least, you should mention that in your answer, not just that you are using the default parameters.

Comment: Thanks, MARSK, But that clip order has nothing to do with it. You will get the same result and you have to add an extra RoundCornerShape with the background if you change the order.

Answer (score 0):

The order of `Modifier`s matters

```
fun IndicatorLight() {
 
    Surface(modifier = Modifier.padding(4.dp)
        .background(Color.Green)) {
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .background(Color.Red)
                .padding(3.dp)
                .clip(RoundedCornerShape(20.dp)) // This right here
        ) {
            Box(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .padding(4.dp)
                    .background(Color.Blue)
            ) {
                Text(
                    text = text,
                    style = TextStyle(
                        color = foreground,
                        fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
                        fontSize = 24.sp
                    )
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

you should clip it AFTER you have applied the background, or you end up applying the background only to the Clipped Area, which is shadowed by its children.

Comment: Ah, thanks. Obvious really. I'd got into the mindset of treating them like a list of properties rather than consecutive operations.

Comment: Actually, it doesn't work as expected. Yes it gets rid of the white cutouts, but it now gives a CutCornerShape- an octagon. Which will be because of the ordering of all the modifiers, but taking a simpler solution that reduces the number of modifiers reduces the scope for screwup.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove `clip` from `Box` modifier and use Surface functions's `shape` argument to have desired layout

```
@Composable
fun IndicatorLight() {
    Surface(
        modifier = Modifier.padding(4.dp),
        shape = RoundedCornerShape(20.dp)
    ) {

        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .background(Color.Red)
                .padding(3.dp)
        ) {
            Box(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .padding(4.dp)
                    .background(Color.Blue)
            ) {
                Text(
                    text = "TEXT",
                    style = TextStyle(
                        color = Color.Black,
                        fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
                        fontSize = 24.sp
                    )
                )
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. It's a useful alternative but I've accepted Marsk's answer because it explains specifically why my attempt didn't work rather than just doing it a different way,